# How to add comma between elements of array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

everyone.

I have an output of multidimensional array(WRONG):

> [ [23], [145], [16], [2], [2], [3], [], ]

I need to have an output like this(GOOD):

> [ [2,3], [1,4,5], [1,6], [2], [2], [3], [], ]

Here's array of my data: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 6 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) [6] => Array ( ) )`

The way I'm trying to do that:

```
print_r($gretimumosarasas);
echo "[ ";
for ($row = 0; $row < count($gretimumosarasas); $row++) {
  echo "[";
  for ($col = 0; $col < count($gretimumosarasas[$row]); $col++) {
    echo $gretimumosarasas[$row][$col];
  }
  echo "], ";
}
echo " ]";
```

Can someone please explain, how to add comma like I wrote an output example below?

If there only way to add coma in second for loop and then search for last symbol index and delete it?

THANK YOU.

Comment: You can use json_encode function for it.

Comment: Are you spoofing a json string here? (not advisable)

Comment: imploding subarray elements is a duplicate question here.

Comment: Do you want to generate JSON? Use the [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function, don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You should add explanation of question.You are not using better approach. Tell us where you want to use this. SO that we can help you.

Comment: I think this question are full of needed information. It have array which I have, also a result I have and a results which I need. I was searching for something like implode. Thank you for helping or trying to understand what I mean. No offence.

Comment: @JustasDambrauskas to doing anything there are several ways but developer always select best option. Your currently requirement are unclear. if you want the same result it is possible but this is not correct way.
foreach loop will implode inner elements with comma and concatenate with these brackets[ ]. Than you have a string and concatenate with [ in start and ] in end.

Answer (score -1):

While I am extremely nervous of the fact you appear to generating code from your code (here be dragons!) its simple enough.

```
function array_formatter($arr)
{
   $temp=array();
   foreach ($arr as $v) {
     $temp[] = is_array($v) ? array_formatter($v) : $v; 
   }
   return '[' . implode(',', $temp) . ']';  
}
```

BTW PHP arrays are not multi-dimensional, they are nested. Nested arrays can emulate multi-dimensional arrays, but your example data is not multi-dimensional itself.

Comment: This answer provides a json-decode-able output string.

Comment: Thanks for the edit mickmackusa. Yes, json_encode may have met the requirement, but comes with a lot of side effects which were not addressed by the OP - hence the reason for a PHP solution. Was it your downvote?